# Displaying images from mysql using php

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I want to display images from my database. The data type of my image field is BLOB. I used a code in some other question in this site but the code does not work. I want to display images inside the info window of Google maps. Based on the screen shot the image tag is displaying however the image itself is not.

[[image: image]]

My Code:

```
<?php 
    require "connect.php";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblLocation";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo "<script>

        function initMap() {

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var uluru = {lat: 14.617766, lng: 121.057154};
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 4,
              center: uluru
            });";
            if ($count > 0){
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "var content = '<div class=".'content'.">'+
                                            '<img src=".'data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image'])."'/>'+
                                            '<p>".$row['address']."</p>'+
                                            '<span class=".'label'.">Branch:</span>'+
                                            '<span class=".'details'.">".$row['branch']."</span>'+
                                            '<span class=".'label'.">Province:</span>'+
                                            '<span class=".'details'.">".$row['province']."</span>'+
                                            '<span class=".'label'.">Phone:</span>'+
                                            '<span class=".'details'.">".$row['phone']."</span>'+
                                            '<span class=".'label'.">Latitude:</span>'+
                                            '<span class=".'details'.">".$row['lat']."</span>'+
                                            '<span class=".'label'.">Longitude:</span>'+
                                            '<span class=".'details'.">".$row['lng']."</span>'+
                                            '<button class=".'btn-edit'.">Edit</button>'+
                                            '<button class=".'btn-delete'.">Delete</button>'+
                                        '</div>';";

                                      echo  "var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                content:content,
                                                position:{ lat:{$row['lat']}, lng:{$row['lng']} },
                                                map: map
                                        });

                                        marker.addListener('click', function(event) {
                                            infowindow.open( map, this );
                                            infowindow.setContent( this.content );
                                            infowindow.setPosition( event.latLng );
                                        }.bind( marker ));";

                }
            }

        echo "}
        </script>";
?>
```

Comment: What output are you getting right now? Or is it showing any error?

Comment: The image tag is displaying however the image from my database is not showing please refer to the screenshot to see what i meant

Comment: Can you open image URL in new tab and see what is it showing?

Comment: I visited the consolse here what it says Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL

Comment: How large are the images typically? If more than 100k, say, then I wouldn't recommend this approach. I suspect you're exceeding the max character limit- but I may be mistaken.

Comment: The image is less than 20k